# Which function to use in r for following binomial distribution

Tags: r

I have a random variable Y, which follows a binomial distribution with parameters n=250 and p=0.02. How can I find a variable X, that makes P(Y ≤ X) ≈ 0.93 true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qbinom` can be used to find the `p`th quantile of the binomial distribution.

```
qbinom(0.93, size = 250, prob = 0.02) 
#> [1] 8
```